# Do games run in the background by default? (Unity) iOS and Andriod

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I'm a bit confused due to the exit on suspend function being removed on Unity 2020. Do games created with unity run in the background on ios and/or android?

I'd like to create a save function on OnApplicationQuit so it will autosave when exiting the game, although that won't work if the game is just suspended. So I'm wondering if it exits the game when you press the home button by default to know if I need to do any extra work.

I haven't been able to find any current questions about this so I'm sorry if it's been asked before!

Thanks!